# Returing the HTTPResponse in chunks of buffered stream

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have an API which takes a request and returns a HTTP response but the response content is very huge.I want the response to be chunked into small pieces and return the response in the buffered stream kind of like in cases of videos and images[(sample example)](http://www.webmonkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/rickastley.jpg).

How to give back the response in this way?Can someone give me a sample code of implementing it in HttpServlet responses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. The Servlet container will take care of this for you. Just write to the OutputStream obtained from the response and let the container do the hard work.